# Firebase database transaction with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

How are we supposed to use transactions with version 5.0.0-rc.7 of AngularFire2?

I currently have the following:

```
this.db.database.ref('path/to/my/count').transaction(count => {
      console.log(count);
      return count + 1;
    });
```

However the count is always passed to callback argument of transaction method as null even though the value in Firebase database is set to 1.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After googling further, I have found that the following works:

```
this.db.object('path/to/my/count').query.ref.transaction(count => count ? ++count : 1);
```

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1222)